# If then else HTML/CSV file

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently building an organisation chart for my company using an html code (pasted below) build by the genius Mr Bostock. The code is calling a .csv file (flare.csv) where I am organizing my data (3 different columns: Employee Name/Employee span of control (5 ranges)/Employee Salary (6 ranges)).

I want to know if it is possible to change the color of the dots/circles on the diagram depending on the two parameters Span of control and Salary (Ranges).

Maybe a diagram for Span of control and another one for Salary.

Let s say if the Span of control of that employee is between 1 and 3 (Flare.csv file) then his circle on the chart will be yellow.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Cheers,
Alex

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node circle {
  fill: #999;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.node--internal circle {
  fill: #555;
}

.node--internal text {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #555;
  stroke-opacity: 0.4;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="900"></svg>
<script src="d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 20) + ")");

var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf(".")); });

var cluster = d3.cluster()
    .size([360, width / 2 - 120]);

d3.csv("flare.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var root = stratify(data)
      .sort(function(a, b) { return a.height - b.height || a.id.localeCompare(b.id); });

  cluster(root);

  var link = g.selectAll(".link")
      .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return "M" + project(d.x, d.y)
            + "C" + project(d.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
            + " " + project(d.parent.x, (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2)
            + " " + project(d.parent.x, d.parent.y);
      });

  var node = g.selectAll(".node")
      .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf"); })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + project(d.x, d.y) + ")"; });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 2.5);

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x < 180 === !d.children ? 6 : -6; })
      .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 === !d.children ? "start" : "end"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x < 180 ? d.x - 90 : d.x + 90) + ")"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.id.substring(d.id.lastIndexOf(".") + 1); });
});

function project(x, y) {
  var angle = (x - 90) / 180 * Math.PI, radius = y;
  return [radius * Math.cos(angle), radius * Math.sin(angle)];
}

</script>
```